# React filter payload arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs, payload

I need help filtering an array of different values.Im using React. Thank you in advance!!!

I have a payload that contains 3 different types of arrays, each type of array has the following key values.

myPayload : array(3)

```
  0: {name: “John “ , age: “24” , height: “174cm” , **type:
   “student”**}.
  1: {name: “Jane”  , age: “49” , height: “168cm” ,**type: “teacher”**}
  2: { name: “schoolName” , country: “UnitedStated” , state: “IL”, 
   **type:”building”**}
```

Cards of type "student" & "teacher" contain the same fields but the "building" card has different fields from the others.

I am rendering the arrays as cards and my goal is to be able to search through all values of the arrays/cards.

This is what I have in my `cards.reducer`

```
import { FILTER_CARDS, FETCH_CARDS } from '../X/Y';

const initialState = { myPayload: [], filteredPayload: [] };

    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        const { type, myPayload = [], value } = action;
        const handler = {
            [FETCH_CARDS]: {
                ...state,
                myPayload,
            },
            [FILTER_CARDS]: {
                ...state,
                filteredPayload: state.myPayload.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().match(value)),
            },
        };

        return handler[type] || state;
    }
```

The above only filters through the "name" field of each card.

I tried filtering through all values (name, age, height, type, schoolName, country, state) by making changes to "FILTER_CARDS" but that breaks and gives me an error of

> "cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

```
[FILTER_CARDS]: {
            ...state,
            filteredPayload: (state.myPayload.type == ('student' || 'teacher')
                    ? (state.myPayload.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().match(value)),
                    state.myPayload.filter(({ age }) => age.toLowerCase().match(value)),
                    state.myPayload.filter(({ height }) => height.toLowerCase().match(value)))
                    : (state.myPayload.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().match(value)),
                    state.myPayload.filter(({ country }) => country.toLowerCase().match(value)),
                    state.assetsPayload.filter(({ state }) => state.toLowerCase().match(value)))),
        },
```

any input on how to filter through all values in this scenario?

Comment: to me, it seems like, the state.myPayload is not set. The state.myPayload does not have any value. hint (state = initialState)

Comment: i think you could just do a computed property access for dynamic properties, something like: `state.myPayload.filter((item) => item[type] === value` or something similar

Comment: @Sodhisaab in the console myPayload is loaded and the values are being fetched correctly, its just filtering the values thats confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following

```
filteredPayload: state. myPayload.filter(item => {
                switch (item.type) {
                case 'building':
                    return (
                        item.name.toLowerCase().match(value)
                            || item.country.toLowerCase().match(value)
                            || item.state.toLowerCase().match(value)
                    );
                case 'student':
                case 'teacher':
                    return (
                        item.name.toLowerCase().match(value)
                            || item.age.toLowerCase().match(value)
                            || item.height.toLowerCase().match(value)
                    );
                }

                return item;
            }),
```

Thank you all for helping out ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You could just search in the values of the object, so you do not really need to care about the key names.

```js
filteredPayload: state.myPayload.filter(item => (
  Object.values(item).some(objValue => (
    objValue.toLowerCase().match(value)
  ))
))
```

Comment: I get an error 'cannot convert undefined or null to an object'

Comment: @CatGirl19 indeed, i had forgotten to add item in the `Object.values`. updated answer.